# Django-Celery progress bar

Tags: django, django-celery

I use:

1. Celery
2. Django-Celery
3. RabbitMQ

I can see all my tasks in the Django admin page, but at the moment it has just a few states, like:

- RECEIVED
- RETRY
- REVOKED
- SUCCESS
- STARTED
- FAILURE
- PENDING

It's not enough information for me. Is it possible to add more details about a running process to the admin page? Like *progress bar* or *finished jobs counter* etc.

I know how to use the Celery logging function, but a GUI is better in my case for some reasons.

So, is it possible to send some tracing information to the Django-Celery admin page?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am starting to try figuring this out myself. Start by defining a PROGRESS state exactly as explained on the [Celery userguide](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#custom-states), then all you need is to insert a js in your template that will update your progress bar.

Answer (score 36):

Here's my minimal progress-reporting Django backend using your setup. I'm still a Django n00b and it's the first time I'm messing with Celery, so this can probably be optimized.

```
from time import sleep

from celery import task, current_task
from celery.result import AsyncResult

from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.utils import simplejson as json
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url


@task()
def do_work():
    """ Get some rest, asynchronously, and update the state all the time """
    for i in range(100):
        sleep(0.1)
        current_task.update_state(state='PROGRESS',
            meta={'current': i, 'total': 100})


def poll_state(request):
    """ A view to report the progress to the user """
    if 'job' in request.GET:
        job_id = request.GET['job']
    else:
        return HttpResponse('No job id given.')

    job = AsyncResult(job_id)
    data = job.result or job.state
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), mimetype='application/json')


def init_work(request):
    """ A view to start a background job and redirect to the status page """
    job = do_work.delay()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('poll_state') + '?job=' + job.id)


urlpatterns = patterns('webapp.modules.asynctasks.progress_bar_demo',
    url(r'^init_work$', init_work),
    url(r'^poll_state$', poll_state, name="poll_state"),
)
```

Comment: On newer versions I think the idiom is to do `@task(bind=True)` and then call `self.update_state`. Performance-wise am not sure which is better.

Answer (score 7):

Thank @Florian Sesser for your example!

I made a complete Django app that show the progress of create 1000 objects to the users at http://iambusychangingtheworld.blogspot.com/2013/07/django-celery-display-progress-bar-of.html

Everyone can download and use it!

Comment: Thanks for the blog, but the code is no longer available.

Comment: Here is the project folder:   https://www.dropbox.com/sh/o9p92yxhpdx58yh/AABBpO912y3NKgXXU4QeLHAFa?dl=0

Comment: Your approach is not applicable for a single file with couple megabytes of any specific cpu based task.

Answer (score 6):

I would recommend a library called [celery-progress](https://github.com/czue/celery-progress) for this. It is designed to make it as easy as possible to drop-in a basic end-to-end progress bar setup into a django app with as little scaffolding as possible, while also supporting heavy customization on the front-end if desired. Lots of docs and references for getting started in the README.

Full disclosure: I am the author/maintainer of said library.

Comment: Can you please provide a working example? I'm stuck with celery-progress

Comment: @MuhammadUmarFarooq feel free to file an issue in celery-progress with the specific problem you're facing and I'll take a look as soon as I can

Comment: Sir, instead of resolving individual issues, can you please provide a github demo. So that, a person can checkout a desired commit as per libraries versions. Thanks

Comment: Or please just mention the versions on which you built your demos, I'm not sure but I think django/celery latest versions are causing the problem.

Comment: The latest demo is running on Django 3.0.5 and Celery 4.4.0 which I believe are the latest as of this date. @MuhammadUmarFarooq