# Is it possible to show progress bar of django celery task?

Tags: django, celery, django-celery, djcelery

I am using database backend in django celery. The task information is stored in a table called: `celery_taskmeta` in database.
This is my task:

```
@celery.task
def file_transfer(password, source12, destination):
    result = subprocess.Popen(['sshpass', '-p', password, 'rsync', '-az', source12, destination], 
                                    stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
    return result
```

I am calling the task like this:

```
file_transfer.s(password, source12, destination)
```

Now I want to show the user the progress of their task and time remaining in the Django template. How can I do that?

Comment: No it isn't the topic may be same but the answer is not very clear in that question.

Comment: Why are you always marking my question negative? Do you have some sort of grudge against me?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe my answer to [Django-Celery progress bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7380373/django-celery-progress-bar) is of help (also posted the code to DjangoSnippets, that's how proud I am of that few lines http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2898/ )

Comment: Are you the author? How can I implement this?

Comment: Yes I am. I implemented a progress bar for a long-running job using AJAX by polling (0.5s interval) the poll_state view and then using the percentage it gives for the 'width' CSS attribute of a inner div (like in <div class="progressbar"><div class="done"></div></div> . Sorry for taking so long BTW, I did not see your question earlier :(

Comment: Thanks for the snippet, is it possible for you to share the front end code too?

Comment: Demonedge: I don't have it anymore, I am afraid. IIRC, I just had a div within a div that had its `width` set to the percent value retrieved from the backend every second or so.